# Missing toolbar in the External Editor in jmeter plugin for netbeans

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, netbeans-8.1

When opening a .jmx file in NetBeans via the jmeter-plugin, the top toolbar in the editor window is missing, along with some menu options. See the two screenshots: [Screenshot from Netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCawW.png).
[Screenshot from jmeter standalone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pVGd.png)

Anyone know if it's possible to access the "full" version of the jmeter editor from within Netbeans (i.e. by right-clicking on the .jmx file in the project and choosing "External Edit"), and if so, how?.

Comment: in NetBeans if you go to Options menu, do you see Toolbar option checked or unchecked?

Comment: Hi, I as far as I can see, there is no Options menu in NB (8.1). There is a Tools menu with an Options entry, but here is no Toolbar option to check/uncheck. The same goes for the JMeter plugin.